# I am trying to write python script for copy and renaming the files

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What approach should be for below scenario?**

I have multiple files and want to copy all files from one directory to other directory and also rename the files like below.

Source Directory: A
example1.txt

example2.txt

example3.txt

Destination Directory:B

example1_19930221.txt

example2_19930221.txt

example3_19930221.txt

command: hadoop distcp /A/* /B/

Comment: Why no use `cp` command?

Comment: yes i can use cp also.but here i want to use hadoop distcp command. what should be approach for copying and renaming the files.

Comment: @bigbounty Seconded. This is easy in Bash: `cd A; for f in example[1-3].txt; do cp $f ../B/${f%.*}_19930221${f#*.}; done`

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Check out [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: You say "below is my question", but nothing you have written here is a question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
shutil.move(source_path , destination_path.replace(filename, filename + "_19930221"))
```